# Lost in jQuery .each()

Tags: php, jquery

In the script below, I'm trying to parse through a select list and for each option, call a php that returns a value (psuedo true/false) based on the options "value" attribute.

However, when I'm inside the $.get [to evaluate the return value and execute script against the current option in the each(),] I can't figure out how to reference the current option element in order to modify it.

```
$('#my_Select').click(
    function(){ 
        $('#my_Select option').each(
            function(){
                $.get(
                    '<?php echo getStyle.php',{option: $(this).val()},
                    function(response){
                        alert($(this).val()); //Returns empty alert. Should return value of current option
                        //$(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
                        //if (response.Success){$(this).attr("disabled","disabled");}
                    });
            });
    });
```

Here's the php script for reference...

```
<?php 
    //getStyle.php

    $myOption = $_REQUEST['option'];
    $file = "styles/".$myOption."/style.css";
    //echo json_encode(file_exists($file));
        if (!file_exists($file))
        {
        $Response = array('Success' => true);
        }
        else
        {
        $Response = array('Success' => false);
        }
    echo json_encode($Response);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` within the `get` success callback won't refer to the element anymore (*any* time there's a new function, `this` within the function may be different from `this` outside of it, and probably will be; [more here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)).

You can solve it like this, using the closure you already have:

```
$('#my_Select').click(
    function(){ 
        $('#my_Select option').each(
            function(){
                // ===> Remember the option here, in a variable your callback will close over
                var option = $(this);
                $.get(
                    '<?php echo getStyle.php',{option: option.val()},
                    function(response){
                        // ===> Use the variable below
                        alert(option.val()); //Returns empty alert. Should return value of current option
                        //option.attr("disabled","disabled");
                        //if (response.Success){option.attr("disabled","disabled");}
                    });
            });
    });
```

Or you can use `ajax` instead of `get` (`get` is just a wrapper anyway) and use the `context` parameter to tell jQuery what to use for `this` when calling your callbacks:

```
$('#my_Select').click(
    function(){ 
        $('#my_Select option').each(
            function(){
                $.ajax({
                   url:     '<?php echo getStyle.php',
                   data:    {option: $(this).val()},
                   context: this,
                   success: function(response){
                            alert($(this).val()); //Returns empty alert. Should return value of current option
                            //$(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
                            //if (response.Success){$(this).attr("disabled","disabled");}
                       }
                    });
            });
    });
```

---

**Edit**: Below, @Hakre asked, referring to the first example above:

> Due to concurrency, doesn't the value of `option` is unpredictable within the callback function?

The answer is no, but it's a very good question. The reason lies at the heart of how JavaScript resolves free symbols (e.g., stand-alone "variable" names) and how closures work.

When a function is called, the JavaScript interpreter creates something called an "execution context" for that specific function call. That execution context has something we'll call the "variable object" that holds the variables and such related to this specific call to the function (technically they're held on the [deep breath] *binding object* of the *variable context* of the *execution context* — gotta love spec-speak).

Functions created within that function call keep a reference to the variable object for the execution context in which they were created; this is how closures work. The interpreter resolves a free symbol by looking on the variable object for *this* function call to see if there's a matching variable (I'm simplifying here). If there isn't, it looks at the variable object for the containing execution context, and then to the one outside that, etc., etc., until it gets to the global context. (This is how global variables work; they're a natural consequence of closures.) This chain of variable objects is called the *scope chain*.

So in the above, there are multiple `option` variables, each intrinsically tied to the `get` callback defined in the same call. So that callback sees the correct `option` variable, regardless of timing.

Comment: Due to concurrency, doesn't the value of `option` is unpredictable within the callback function?

Comment: @hakre: No. Every call to the `each` callback gets its *own* copy of `option`, and each closure created within that callback refers to its specific copy. I'll add a note explaining why.

Comment: Crowder: Cool, then why not even add a `var self = this;` and it can be referred to `self` inside of the callback as of `this`?

Comment: @hakre: That's what we're doing with `option`. I was killing two birds with one stone: 1. Taking advantage of the closure, and 2. Avoiding unnecessary, repeated calls to `$()`. (I've added that explanation, btw.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I *know*, great stuff!

Comment: +1 for the explano on $(this) context and for answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

your function can accept the element's index and the element itself:
`jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )`
see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)
as a side note- you're calling the server in a loop.
generally that isn't good practice, since calls to the server are very expensive.
consider changing your server function to accept an array of values, and using your loop to create that array, then after the loop make just one server call.

Comment: Yes, I was answering the `each` issue, but by far it would be better to call the server *once*. :-)